# python xgboost DMatrix - get feature values or convert to np.array

Tags: python, xgboost, cross-validation, model-evaluations

I'm trying to create a custom evaluation metric (feval) function for xgboost.cv. It should process some of the training features, however I can't find a way to extract features from `xgboost.DMatrix()` object (only labels)..

As I was suggested it can be done with first making a DMatrix slice then saving it to a svmlight file and finally reading it with scikit-learn, but is there a more elegant way if doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert DMatrix to NumPy array using **dmatrix2np**:

```
from dmatrix2np import dmatrix_to_numpy

converted_np_array = dmatrix_to_numpy(dmatrix)
```

It's open-source, you can see its code [here](https://github.com/aporia-ai/dmatrix2np).

Answer (score 2):

> Currently we cannot direct extract data matrix from DMatrix, mainly due to DMatrix is a internal data structure that may or maynot sit in memory.

--by tqchen commented on 3 Aug 2015

([Source](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/422))